# Flutter iOS App Calls Cloud Function from Wrong Firebase Project Despite Updating GoogleService-Info.plist

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions

I have a Flutter iOS app that was mistakenly calling a cloud function from an incorrect Firebase project. To correct this, I downloaded and replaced the GoogleService-Info.plist with the correct one. Additionally, I performed the following steps:

1. Ran flutter clean
2. Ran flutter pub get
3. Navigated to the iOS directory (cd ios) and ran pod update
4. Cleaned the build folder in Xcode

I also noticed that the CFBundleURLSchemes in the info.plist file contained OAuth data from the previous incorrect project, which I have replaced. Despite taking all these steps, when I connect my iPhone via USB and run the app, it still calls the cloud function from the previous Firebase project.

What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that my app calls the cloud function from the correct Firebase project?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the Runner is using GoogleService-Info.plist from wrong path, in my case is from my downloads folder